# Can Laravel-Forge work with a CI cloud service?

Tags: laravel, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, laravel-forge

My team and I were setting everything up so that **Forge** was in charge of deployment exclusively, while a **CI cloud service** would run unit/integration tests on each push to **develop** or **master** (staging or production, respectively).

Given the fact that **Forge** will trigger a deployment on each push to **master** (or any other branch), where does the CI server takes place in this model? Can I get a quick explanation of the workflow (and if possible an example CI cloud that would work with it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next to the auto deploy trigger **Forge** provides you a deploy-hook-url that can be called to trigger the deployment script. Usually the **ci cloud service** provides a way to customize the test/deployment process with some sort of bash scripts (curl) or gives an option to call an url after a successful run.

For example I used to use **codeship** for ci and they have an option in the settings called *deployment* where i could insert a custom script which calls the trigger url like `curl -X GET https://forge.laravel.com/servers/xxx/sites/xxx/deploy/http?token=xxx`

1. deactivate the aug-deploy trigger
2. customize the ci settings and call the forge-hook after successful run